# Inspect button in browser and find onClick function

Tags: html, debugging

I'm new to a project and have a website where I need to find the typescript code to a specific button click (which function will be called when I click on the button). If its a backend call I can click the button and view the API request in the network tab, but if it's just a frontend function that runs on button click, I don't know how to get to the code just from looking at the minified HTML:

This is e.g. the code that I see in the developer console. How do I find the function belonging to the onClick event of this button?

```
<button _ngcontent-uad-c275="" mat-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-button mat-button-base" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-9" cdk-describedby-host="">
  <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
```

(the website automatically gets uglified/minified at compilation, or I don't really know what it's called, but you can't really search for the HTML code that gets displayed in the console. When I search for <button _ngcontent-uad-c275="", I find nothing in the code) I'm using the chrome browser.

Comment: In Chrome dev tools, when inspecting an element, there is an option (alongside "Styles", "Computed", etc.) to view the "Event Listeners" for that element.  Which can optionally include event listeners on ancestor elements as well (for propagation/delegation).  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Since functions are usually bound to the DOM (which is generated from the HTML) by JavaScript, looking at the HTML source code alone won't help since it doesn't contain the binding instruction.